# DOJO: dojox.grid.TreeGrid + checkbox How to

Tags: javascript, tree, dojo

Is it possible to place chceckboxes inside LazyTreeGrid ?

Maybe there is some plugin that would automatically update the selected object and fire onSelectionChanged event ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: The [API Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/) shows that the LazyTreeGrid has a `widgetsInTemplate` property, so You can place checkboxes inside the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The treegrid has a bug in terms of checkbox.
    `{ field: "isSelected",name: "Selected", width: "6em", editable:"true",alwaysEditing:"true",cellType:"dojox.grid.cells.Bool"}`,

Will show the checkbox. But it will not provide you the value when you check/uncheck the value.

To fix it, you need to do this:
 `{ field: "recvid",name: "Selected", width: "6em",formatter:formatCheckBox}`,

```
 function formatCheckBox(value,rowIndex) 
    {
        var icon;
        //var item = e.grid.getItem(rowIndex);
        //var itemName = item.itemName.toString();
        var id = value + "|" + 'Selected';
        //console.log(rowIndex + " "+value);

         if (rowIndex!=-1)
         {
          icon = "<input  style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" id='" + id + "' name='grid_item_checkbox' type='checkbox' />&#xA0;";
         }
        return icon;
    }
```

Comment: @Mark Wu,Seba

If I check the checkbox for the parent node in lazy tree , all it's children need to get checked as well.How could I go about this.

Answer (score -1):

[Dijit Tree with Multi State Checkboxes](http://www.thejekels.com/dojo/Dijit_Tree_MultiState_Chkbox.html) (appeared as first result when Googling)

Comment: dijit Tree is not TreeGrid !! Different types of trees.